# What's the meaning of `indistinguishable` in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I was reading the documentation of an Emacs Lisp function called `eql`:

```
Return t if the two args are eq or are indistinguishable numbers.
```

What's the meaning of `indistinguishable` here? I'd been searching through the documentation but didn't find an explanation.

Comment: It means numerically equal.

Comment: The word is being used with its normal English meaning, it's not a technical term that they need to define.

Comment: @Drew -- `eq` is for "indistinguishable as lisp objects"; indistinguishable numbers need not be identical objects, which is why `eql` expands upon `eq` to accommodate numbers.

Comment: Sorry; yes, I meant `eq` for that comment.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't mean numerically equal, because 1 and 1.0 are numerically equal, yet distinguishable. To be fully accurate, the documentation should say something like "indistinguishable representations of the same number".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eq` predicate returns `t` only when comparing identical objects. But two values which compare equal are not guaranteed to be the same object; two literals with the same value are not even guaranteed to be the same object. So, `(eq 1 1)` may or may not evaluate to `t`. For number types `eql` compares values, so that `(eql 1 1)` will always evaluate to `t`. But, `eql` is a bit more subtle: `(eql 1 1.0)` will evaluate to `'nil` since `1` and `1.0` are not *indistinguishable*, i.e., they do not share the same type. So, in the context of the quote, indistinguishable means that the operands have the same type and the same value.

Comment: I found that `(eql +0.0 -0.0)` evaluated to `nil`. How could it be? `+0.0` and `-0.0` are of the same type and the same value. If *indistinguishable* means the same type and the same value, then `(eql +0.0 -0.0)` should evaluate to `t`.

Comment: IEEE floating point 0.0 and -0.0 have different bit patterns. The Elisp Manual says that [they are `=`, but some operations can distinguish between them](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Float-Basics). Presumably `eql` is meant to be one of those operations. 0.0 and -0.0 are _numerically equal_, but they have different values. One way to see this is to observe that 1.0 / 0.0 => infinity, but 1.0 / -0.0 => -infinity.

Comment: When I evaluate `(/ 1.0 0.0)` in an Elisp buffer I get `1.0e+INF`, and evaluating `(/ 1.0 -0.0)` yields `-1.0e+INF`. If `0.0` and `-0.0` were the same value, these results should agree.